# Estimate of Fourier transform of compactly supported function.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, pseudo-differential-operators

The following argument is quoted from a book about Pseudodifferential operator. I am confused about the estimate of Fourier transform of a compactly supported function.

For a smooth function $p(x,\xi)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n,$ satisfying the estimate
\begin{equation*}
|\partial_x^\beta \partial_\xi^\alpha p(x,\xi) | \leq C_{\alpha,\beta} (1+|\xi|)^{m-|\alpha|}, \ \forall (x,\xi) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n,
\end{equation*}
and $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ is a constant number only depending on $\alpha,\beta.$ We assume further $p(x,\xi)$ has compact support in $x,$ that is, there exists $K$ independent on $\xi,$ such that $p(x,\xi)=0$ when $|x|\geq K.$

Now consider Fourier transform of $p(x,\xi)$ with respect to $\xi,$ the Fourier dual variable is $\eta \in \mathbb{R}^n,$ the author said that "concerning the support of $p(x,\xi)$, we have the following estimate"
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{F}_{x \rightarrow \eta}(p)(\eta-\xi,\xi) \leq C (1+|\xi|)^m(1+|\eta-\xi|)^{-h},
\end{equation*}
for all $h \geq 0,$ and $C$ is a positive number independent on $h.$

I have no idea how to deduce the estimate. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If this bound is independent on $h$, why can't we take $h \to \infty$ when $\eta \neq \xi$? Did the author say that the support of the fourier transform is only on the set $\eta = \xi$? My inclination was to integrate by parts, but using this and the compact support only guarantees a constant $C$ that depends on $h$.

Comment: I think you are right.  Thank you!